# What is the best/most performant way to push data from a webpage to a .net program

Tags: .net, sql-server, webserver

I have a webpage on an Apache web server which communicates over PHP to a SQL Server database.

I also run a .NET program which communicates to an industrial controller.

Now I am looking for the most performant and fastest way to send a string from this webpage to the .NET program (when I press a button on the webpage).

The way I know is to use a timer in the .NET program set the interval up to 10ms and query every tick a row in the database which will be filled/updated when the button in on the webpage will be pressed.

But I think that there should be a better way these days to do something like this!?

Is there a way to communicate directly from the webpage to the .NET program without the database?

Comment: I see couple of options here, but in all of them there will have to be some development happening in php to emit an actual event or send message and in .net to consume it. Have a look at either of: gRPC (https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/basics/), Web Sockets (http://socketo.me/docs/), Service Bus (https://github.com/php-service-bus/service-bus).

Comment: @Kamil: Thx. I think I take a closer look at gRPC.